# Category theory lambda cube?

Tags: lambda-calculus, ct.category-theory, dependent-type, typed-lambda-calculus

If simply typed lambda calculus corresponds to cartesian closed categories, what types of categories do other calculi in the lambda cube correspond to?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube

Comment: I think https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+category might be of interest to you. In the references it says that dependent type theory is the interal language of locally cartesian closed categories. Also there is a paper called "Categorical Semantics for Higher Order Polymorphic Lambda Calculus" which discussed categorial semantics of the polymorphic lambda calculus (System F), but I do not know enough to understand it.

Comment: I'm not aware of an explicit formulation of such a cube, but Bart Jacobs [1] goes through various structures and axioms that can be required of fibrations that correspond to different type system. One might be able to assemble a cube from the chapter/sections and combinations thereof.  [1] B. Jacobs, Categorical Logic and Type Theory. Amsterdam: North Holland, 1999.